# C2440 error when using typecasting operator overload with Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I'm hitting a C2440 error:

```
C:\code>cl test.cpp /EHsc                       

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86                 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                                      

test.cpp                                                                                        
test.cpp(18) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'D<TYPE,SELECTOR>' to 'int'
    with
    [
        TYPE=int,
        SELECTOR=int
    ]
    Ambiguous user-defined-conversion
```

When I try to compile the following test code with visual studio 10, it seems to be working fine with `clang -Weverything` and armcc.

Is there a particular reason this isn't working, and is there a workaround aside from "don't do that"?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TYPE, typename SELECTOR = int> struct D  {
    TYPE x;
    D() : x(2) {}
    D(TYPE X) : x(X) {}

    operator const TYPE&() const { return x; }
};
template <typename TYPE> struct D<TYPE, int> : public D<TYPE, char> {
    D() : D<TYPE, char>(3) {}
    operator TYPE&() { return D<TYPE, char>::x; }
};

int main() {

    D<int, int> test3;
    int t3 = test3;

    D<int, char> test2;
    int t2 = test2;

    std::cout << +t3 << " " << +t2 << "\n";  // Expected output "3 2" (which we get from clang)
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I'm aware that the `D<TYPE, int>` case is providing an lvalue, and `D<TYPE, non-int>` case is providing only an rvalue. That is quite intentional.

Comment: worked fine with gcc

Comment: So does an `operator int&()` in the derived class hide `operator const int&()` from the base class, or is it an overload? Who knows!

Comment: If signature is identical so it override but possible toacces with namespace specification. This example different by const, so it is possible o call const and non const version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ambiguous user-defined-conversion`

Ambiguous is the keyword.

```
D<int, int> test3;
int t3 = test3;
```

Here the compiler doesn't know wether to use `const int &D<int, char>::operator const int &()` or `int &D<int, int>::operator int &()`.

The problem is that `t3` is `int` and not `int&` or `const int&`.
If you actually work with references everything works fine (or at least as expected):

```
D<int, int> test3;
int& t31 = test3; //OK
const int& t32 = test3; //OK

D<int, char> test2;
int& t21 = test2; //Doesn't work
const int& t22 = test2; //OK
```

The problem is for the compiler to decide wether to use the const version of the base class or the non-const version of the inheriting class.

I would recommend you overload the const version of the operator in the inheriting class, so that the compiler can choose which one to use from this class only:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TYPE, typename SELECTOR = int> struct D {
    TYPE x;
    D() : x(2) {}
    D(TYPE X) : x(X) {}

    operator const TYPE&() const { return x; }
};
template <typename TYPE> struct D<TYPE, int> : public D<TYPE, char> {
    D() : D<TYPE, char>(3) {}

    operator const TYPE&() const { return D<TYPE, char>::x; }
    operator TYPE&() { return D<TYPE, char>::x; }
};

int main() {

    D<int, int> test3;
    int t3 = test3; //OK
    int& t31 = test3; //OK
    const int& t32 = test3; //OK

    D<int, char> test2;
    int t2 = test2; //OK
    //int& t21 = test2; //Doesn't work
    const int& t22 = test2; //OK

    std::cout << +t3 << " " << +t2 << "\n";  // Expected output "3 2" (which we get from clang)
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Other ways to address this problem:**

You can now manually cast to `int&`

```
D<int, int> test3;
int t3 = (int&)test3;
```

or manually cast to `const int&`

```
D<int, int> test3;
int t3 = (const int&)test3;
```

or explicitly call the functions

```
D<int, int> test3;
int t3 = test3.operator int &();
```

or

```
D<int, int> test3;
int t3 = test3.operator const int &();
```

or you could make both function `const`

```
template <typename TYPE> struct D<TYPE, int> : public D<TYPE, char> {
    D() : D<TYPE, char>(3) {}
    operator const TYPE&() const { return D<TYPE, char>::x; }
};
```

Or you could just remove the redifinition of the function (As TYPE doesn't change).

```
template <typename TYPE, typename SELECTOR = int> struct D {
    TYPE x;
    D() : x(2) {}
    D(TYPE X) : x(X) {}

    operator const TYPE&() const { return x; }
};

template <typename TYPE> struct D<TYPE, int> : public D<TYPE, char> {
    D() : D<TYPE, char>(3) {}
};
```

Yet I guess the latter 2 variants are not what you want because of the `const`.

Comment: The read-only vs read-write aspect of the two versions of the overload is quite intentional. The real case is a featherweight class where the "lookup" function is significantly more complicated than a simple `D<TYPE, char>::x`, with several dozen operator overloads for the lvalue case.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer: And how/why does adding `operator const TYPE&() const` to the derived class resolve the ambiguity? What is the difference between the original variant and the updated variant with regard to ambiguities in overload resolution?

Comment: @jkerian Because your non-const operator overload hides the const operator in your base class. The compiler now has to decide whether you mean to use the version of your derived class or to implicitly cast to your base class and use the operator of your base class. As you do copy-assignment to a non-reference variable it is ambigious.

Comment: @jkerian You may also want to look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152799/does-overriding-a-non-const-virtual-method-hide-a-const-overload

Comment: @Simon Kraemer: Just to point out... if msvs implemented the mechanism in your linked answer, there would be no ambiguity and this wouldn't be an error. (as I presume the other three compilers I tried do)

Answer (score 1):

There are two function of `operator TYPE&()`:

```
public D<int, int>::operator int&() 
private D<int, char>::operator const int&() const
```

possible to call it explicit:

```
int t3 = test3.::D<int, int>::operator int&();
```

concerning gcc is allow to call (if puplic inheritance):

```
int t3 = test3.::D<int, char>::operator const int&();
```

but for msvc isn't

gcc allow both variant and seems it is right:

```
D<int, int> test3;
const D<int, int> test4;

int t3 = test3; // called D<int, int>::operator int&();
int t4 = test4; // called D<int, char>::operator const int&() const;
```

msvc allow only second variant.

msvc does not considers that test3 is not const and does not select const and non const function.

Seems it is msvc bug.

Comment: I have first edition of your code where was private inheritance, so it will be private.

Comment: It turned out that public/private didn't change the error at all, but I had tried changing that before posting.